# How do I display a name for a form that is not its real name?

Tags: ms-access

When a form opens in MS Access, it displays its name on the title bar of the form. I want to hide the real name of my form and display a more user-friendly name on the title bar. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the form's caption property.